# Change route files based upon URI path in Slim 3

Tags: php, html, slim, slim-lang, slim-3

Ok so I have 4 folders all which have their own route.php. So I would like to require the path to each folder based upon the uri path. So for example, if my website path is www.example.com/user then the Slim framework would require the path to controller/users/routes. I'm trying to achiee this using middleware but when I test it I get a "Call to a member function error" so how do I fix this.

Here is my code below:

```
 //determine the uri path then add route path based upon uri
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {
    if (strpos($request->getAttribute('route'), "/user") === 0) {
        require_once('controllers/users/routes.php');
    } elseif (strpos($request->getUri()->getPath(), "/public") === 0) {
        require_once('controllers/public/routes.php');
    } elseif (strpos($request->getUri()->getPath(), "/brand") === 0) {
        require_once('controllers/brands/routes.php');
    }elseif (strpos($request->getUri()->getPath(), "/admin") === 0) {
        require_once('controllers/admin/routes.php');
    }elseif (strpos($request->getUri()->getPath(), "/") === 0) {
        require_once('routes.php');
    }

    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
});
```

So before anything the framework determines the route then adds the required path. But something is not functioning right, any ideas?

Comment: why would you do this?

Comment: to keep the routes separated and only load the route page in the index so it can run faster..or am I not looking it the right way?

Comment: that will not make much difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you shouldn't do this because it shouldn't take much time to register all routes.

But if you want todo this you weed to make some changes to you'r code:

1. `$request->getAttribute('route')` doesn't return the path, it returns the route object of slim

   If you want to use the path use `$request->getUri()->getPath()` instead (it doesn't start with a `/` so the route f.ex is (`/customRoute/test` it returns `customRoute/test`
2. You need to use the `$app` as `$this` in this context is the `ContainerInterface` from Pimple and not the App of slim
3. Make sure you didn't set `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` inside the settings to `true` as it checks which route to execute before the middleware execution.

Here a running example:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->add(function($req, $res, $next) use ($app) {
    if(strpos($req->getUri()->getPath(), "customPath" ) === 0) {
        $app->get('/customPath/test', function ($req, $res, $arg) {
            return $res->write("WUII");
        });
    }
    return $next($req, $res);
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: [This article](https://atwork.realself.com/2015/05/optimizing-slim-routing/) claims that adding additional routes increases load time.